# htaccess перенаправление запросов на поддомен

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Добрый день!

Впал в ступор! Требуется сделать перенаправление запросов с папки `/p/` на поддомен `account.site.org`.

т.е. при открытии в браузере `site.org/p/` у пользователя открывалась страница с `account.site.org`, но в адресной строке все оставалось как прежде (`site.org/p/`)

Написал такой код:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /p/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://account.site.ru/ [NC,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^penguinmail.ru/p/
#RewriteRule account/(.*)$ http://account.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Но браузер пытается послать на сайт `account./`. В чем беда? Как можно реализовать такую задумку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так в .htaccess, который в папке /p/ лежит:

```
# если обращение идет к основному домену
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^penguinmail.ru$
# то делать редирект с удалением папки "p" в начале (если она там есть)
RewriteRule ^(p/)?(.*)$ http://account.penguinmail.ru/$2 [R=301,L,QSA]

# далее остальные правила для поддомена
```

или в .htaccess, который лежит в корне основного домена

```
# если обращение идет к основному домену
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^penguinmail.ru$
# и его папке "p", то делать редирект на поддомен
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ http://account.penguinmail.ru/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# далее остальные правила
```